# Regex to Match All Numbers Except Those in the First Word

Tags: regex

I am having trouble crafting a regex. For example, in the string `A123 4HEL5P6 789` I want to match all the numbers 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 but not 1, 2, 3.

[I have tried](https://regex101.com/r/cPH4cr/1) using negative look behind with the regex `(?<!^\w)\d+` but this matches the numbers in the first word.

**Edit:** Any numbers in the first continuous sequence of characters should not be matched, the first continuous sequence being from start (`^`) to a whitespace (`\s`). In `09B8A HE1LP` only 1 should be matched, not 0, 9, or 8, as these digits are in the first word.

Comment: `[4-9]` matches all numbers from 4 to 9.

Comment: Is there a clear rule defining which numbers you are NOT interested in matching? Like "those coming aside the first alphanumeric character in the string", or something alike ?

Comment: Use `^\w+(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+`

Comment: What is the tool you are using?

Comment: You can optionally consume the first word and use a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): [`(?:^\S+\s+)?(\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/eNXRIG/1) (works as long as you have at least two words in the string)

Comment: I was using Python's `re` module which only supports fixed-width lookbehinds. I switched to PyPy's `regex` which supports variable-width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dialect supports variable-length negative lookbehinds, then this should work:

```js
r = /(?<!^\w*)\d/g

console.log(...'A123 4HEL5P6 789'.match(r))
```

Otherwise, you could use `/^\w*|\d/g` and discard the first match.

Comment: My dialect only supported fixed-width look behinds (but I never specified this in the question). This and the regex given by Wiktor both accomplish what I need for the variable-length dialect. Thanks!